# Is it possible to alter the layout displayed on smaller resolutions through MediaQueries without altering the default layout?

Tags: reactjs, media-queries

I am using "grid-template-columns" layout on my default resolution that makes elements appear as they are intended but on smaller resolutions they are rendered by container priority creating a visual effect that I want to change.

On default resolution: `<Selector>` is rendered at the left of the display, then on the other end of the display is `<Skills>` and then `<p>` below it. On smaller resolutions I want to make it so that the elements render in this layout: `<skills>` then `<selector>` then `<p>` one each below the other.

```
      <div className='container about_container'>

        <div>
          <div>
            <img src={image} alt='Image'/>
          </div>
          <Selector/>
        </div>

        <div>
         <Skills/>
          <div> 
            <p>
            blablabla
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

```
.container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.about_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 75%;
    gap: 5%;
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        gap: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents) on the column wrappers at the narrow breakpoint, so that their layout boxes are replaced by their children, effectively making their children be the children of the grid layout. This then gives us the ability to use [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to reorder the children despite being in different parent elements.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 75%;
  gap: 5%;
}
  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 0;
  }
  
  .contents {
    display: contents;
  }
  
  Selector {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  Skills {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .paragraph-wrapper {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container about_container'>

  <div class="contents">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/48/48" alt='Image' />
    </div>
    <Selector>Selector</Selector>
  </div>

  <div class="contents">
    <Skills>Skills</Skills>
    <div class="paragraph-wrapper">
      <p>
        blablabla
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```